# How to get execution date/logical date in PostgresOperator in Airflow?

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, etl, pipeline

How do I get access to the execution date in the PostgresOperator in Apache Airflow?

With PythonOperator I get it as below

```
def fun(context):
    print(context["execution_date"])
    print(context["logical_date"]) # also the same

task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="python_test",
    python_callable=fun,
)
```

My question is how do I get the same functionality with PostgresOperator.
I have the below task.

```
task = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="task_id",
    postgres_conn_id="local_conn",
    sql="sql/some_query.sql"
)
```

and some_query.sql looks like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE date = '2022-11-10'
```

I want to parameterize the date above with the execution date.
Something like:

```
WHERE date = {{context.logical_date}}
```

How can I achieve that?
also is this the best practice to adjust the behaviour of a task based on a date?

Comment: you can access it like `{{ ds }}` https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the execution_date(Deprecated) or logical_date by pass them as function parameters.

There are a example with the Taskflow Api and Airflow 2.7, try it out !

### Taskflow API

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Taipei")

@task
def fun(logical_date=None):
    logical_date_str = logical_date.astimezone(local_tz).to_date_string()
    local_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="local_conn")
    sql_query = f"""
                SELECT *
                FROM TABLE
                WHERE date = '{logical_date_str}'
                """
    local_df = local_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=sql_query)
    return local_df

@dag(
    dag_id="local_dag",
    schedule=None,
    start_date = datetime(2024, 3, 19, tzinfo=local_tz),
    catchup=False
)

# You could set Task dependencies here
def execute():
    fun()

execute()
```

- make sure you set your own timezone
- After airflow 2.7, you could return Pandas DataFrame directly, if before 2.7, you should return the value you serialize into json like below.

```py
@task
def fun():
    # get pandas dataframe from sql
    return df.to_json()
```

there are some documents about taskflow api:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html
https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-decorators